# How do I compare strings of inputs from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to compare `userN` to `nameDb` and `userP` to `passDb` and if both of the strings matches or does not matches, `loginResult` would changed to 1 on 0.(Where 1 being correct, 0 being false)

[Edit1]: Changed initial `loginResult` to  1 from 0, added 2 print statement at the if else under `login`function

[Edit2]: It seems like there might be a problem with the way I'm comparing strings in my `login` function. Even if both of the strings matches, it still goes to the `else` statement. Resulting in `loginResult` to be always 0.

```
loginResult = 1

userN = input("Username:")
userP = input("Password:")

def login(userN,userP):
    global = loginResult
    nameDb = open("files1", mode ="r")
    passDb = open("files2", mode ="r")

    print("Textfile username:",nameDb.readline())
    print("Textfile password:",passDb.readline())


    if(userN == nameDb.readline() and userP == passDb.readline()):
        loginResult = 1
        print("Ding")
        return
    else:
        loginResult = 0
        print("Dong")

login(userN, userP)

if(loginResult == 1):
    print("Welcome !")
elif(loginResult == 0):*emphasized text*
    print("Error !")
```

**Output:**

Username:Kelvin12

Password:Maxi12

Textfile username: Kelvin12

Textfile password: Maxi12

dong

Error !

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 4.688 s
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Yes that's how you should compare strings. Probably there's leading newline or space from text file which you can `strip()`. What is the current output? Is there any error?

Comment: Hi @Austin, error that I get is that even thought the user input matches both of the the text files, my `loginResult` is still 0. Which thus printing the _"Error !"_  message in my programme.

Answer (score 0):

First of all always use `open` with `with`, then trim and replace newlines from your strings:

```
loginResult = 0

userN = input("Username:")
userP = input("Password:")

def login(userN,userP):
    with open("files1", mode ="r") as nameDb, open("files2", mode ="r") as passDb:
        if(userN == nameDb.readline().strip().replace('\n', '') and userP == passDb.readline().strip().replace('\n', '')):
            loginResult = 1
            return
        else:
            loginResult = 0


login(userN, userP)

if(loginResult == 1):
    print("Welcome !")
elif(loginResult == 0):
    print("Error !")
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried working around based on your code, I am unable to resolve it. Even though user input matches with the text files's strings, the `loginResult` still remained 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign different value to the global variable `loginResult` from within your function. If you want to do that you have to use `global` keyword. You can add just one line to your original code:

```
loginResult = 1

userN = input("Username:")
userP = input("Password:")

def login(userN,userP):

    global loginResult  # now loginResult is global, not local

    nameDb = open("files1", mode ="r")
    passDb = open("files2", mode ="r")

    print("Textfile username:",nameDb.readline())
    print("Textfile password:",passDb.readline())


    if(userN == nameDb.readline() and userP == passDb.readline()):
        loginResult = 1
        print("Ding")
        return
    else:
        loginResult = 0
        print("Dong")

login(userN, userP)

if(loginResult == 1):
    print("Welcome !")
elif(loginResult == 0):*emphasized text*
    print("Error !")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print what type of data nameDb and passDb are? If it is a list, use 'in' not '=='.

Comment: This looks more like a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop it prints out all the content in the in `nameList` as `X` variable.
And if `x` matches `userN`'s strings it will then execute below code.

```
userN = input("Username:")
userP = input("Password:")

with open("file1", mode ="r") as nameDb:
    nameList = nameDb.read().splitlines()

with open("file2", mode ="r") as passDb:
    passList = passDb.read().splitlines() 
#using .read.splitlines removes "\n" in the output

for x in nameList:

    if x == userN:

        loginName = 1

        break
    else:
        loginName = 0
```